# How to write a method in superclass whose parameter type is restricted to another object belonging to the same subclass of the calling object

Tags: java, oop, polymorphism, object-oriented-analysis

I'm new to Java programming. Please consider the following code snippet.

```
public class Animal {
    public void mate( /*what should I put here?*/ anotherAnimal ) {
    }
}

public class Cat extends Animal {
}

public class Dog extends Animal {
}
```

I want to write the method `Animal.mate()` in such a way that, when the method is called from a subclass object, the argument fed to the method must be an object of the same subclass, otherwise a compiler error is triggered. For instance:

```
Cat cat = new Cat();
Dog dog = new Dog();
Animal randomAnimal = new Animal();
Cat trueLove = new Cat();

cat.mate( dog ); // raises a compiler error
cat.mate( randomAnimal ); //compiler error
cat.mate( trueLove ); //passes compiler check
```

Is what I'm asking possible? I have a vague feeling that it might be possible to do it using generics.

Comment: You could use `Animal<A extends Animal>`, `Cat extends Animal<Cat>` and `mate(A partner)`.

Comment: What about: `Animal a = new Cat(); a.mate(new Animal());` Do you expect that to work or not?

Comment: @Sweeper It'd be all the better if you can give me something that makes it work, but I'll be happy enough for something that only makes ``Cat cat = new Cat(); cat.mate( new Cat() )`` work

Comment: So you think `a.mate(new Animal());` should compile? I don't think so. At runtime, `a` stores a `Cat` object though, and `Cat` objects can't mate with `Animal` objects, right?

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to make the compiler prevent all bad calls. Even if you parameterize `Animal`, it would still be possible for something like `cat.mate(dog)` to be executed at runtime.

If this is required by your business logic, then your best bet is to validate, with something *like*:

```
public class Animal {
    public final void mate(Animal anotherAnimal ) {
        if(!this.getClass().equals(anotherAnimal.getClass())) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
    }
}
```

If you're doing this mainly to improve compile-time type checking, then you can use generics, knowing the limitations:

```
class Animal<T extends Animal<T>> {
    public final void mate(T anotherAnimal) {

    }
}
```

This will work if your API users use the subclasses rather than the `Animal` type, and they don't use raw types.

```
Cat c = new Cat();
c.mate(new Cat());
c.mate(new Dog());//fails

Animal animal = c;      //raw type
animal.mate(new Dog()); //only a warning
```

Answer (score 0):

your problem is about to Polymorphism.
use super class as parameter type in mate method.super class is Animal.
this is the code:

```
public class Animal {
public void mate(Animal animal) {
    System.out.println("Animals mating");
}
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Animal";
}

public class Dog extends Animal {
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Dog";
}
public class Cat extends Animal {
@Override
public void mate(Animal obj) {
    System.out.println("cat mating with " + obj );
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "cat";
}}
```

and run your code in main method. errors have gone and this is the answer:

```
cat mating with Dog.
cat mating with Animal.
cat mating with cat.
```

for better answer instead of saying cat or dog , you can define a name field in Animal class.